# How can I select the selected item again in the Listview?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void taskList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (taskList.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            editButton.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            inputTitle.Text = (taskList.SelectedItem as AddItem).Title.Trim();
            editButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

I want to select selecteditem again.
However, selectedChanged works only when the item changes. How can I re-select seleceditem?

Comment: Sounds like some XY problem. What are you actually trying to archive here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this solution is what you need to solve the problem gracefully. Your logic should not depend on selecting an item twice or more. Since you have decided to provided no information, I can't make any recommendations to fix your smelly code.

To set the selected item again to to the current selected item in order to trigger the `SelectionChanged` event you can:

If in scope, simply call the event handler directly:

```
taskList_SelectionChanged(taskList,  
  new SelectionChangedEventArgs(
    Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, 
    new List<object>(), 
    new List<object>() { taskList.SelectedItem }));
```

Or reassign the value either in code-behind or view model:

```
var selectedItem = taskList.SelectedItem;
taskList.SelectedItem = null;
taskList.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a "code-behing"  you could declare a global variable like this:

```
//Type must match the "itemsource" of your tasklist
Type _myGlobalVariable;
```

Assign it to the "SelectedItem" of your tasklist like this:

```
_myGlobalVariable = tasklist.SelectedItem;
```

And you can call "_myGlobalVariable" in whatever event you want.

However if you're using the MVVM aproach, then first you need to create a global property. Something like this:

```
private Type _myPropFul;

public Type MyPropFul
{
    get => __myPropFul;
    set => SetProperty(ref _myPropFul, value);
}
```

And bind it to your collection control like this:

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Bindind MyPropFull}"></ListView>
```